# How to get max value by day?

Tags: javascript, arrays

It seems like a simple question but I cannot found a good solution.
As you can see in the snipet below, I am grouping the array by day and code.
It's what I want to do.
But I have a rule to execute :
If the value for A > 6 or B > 60 **at any point during the day** (only if code is GLLD008) then GLLD008 should become GLLD0015 (A & B are varsyscode)

Output should be :

```
  5 - Thu Sep 06 2018 16:03:10 GMT+0200 (CEST) - GLLD008 - A ( Because A <=6 & no B => GLLD008)
  7 - Mon Sep 10 2018 13:32:28 GMT+0200 (CEST) - GLLD015 - A ( Because A > 6 => GLLD015)
  85 - Wed Sep 05 2018 15:07:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time) - GLLD015 - B
```

If someone can help

Thanks

```js
var myArray = [
  {
    "value": 5,
    "datetime": 1536242590000,
    "code": "GLLD008",
    "varsyscode": "A"
  },
  {
    "value": 7,
    "datetime": 1536579148000,
    "code": "GLLD008",
    "varsyscode": "A"
  },
  {
    "value": 6,
    "datetime": 1536579688000,
    "code": "GLLD008",
    "varsyscode": "A"
  },
  {
    "value": 5,
    "datetime": 1536833430000,
    "code": "GLLD008",
    "varsyscode": "A"
  },
  {
    "value": 85,
    "datetime": 1536152820000,
    "code": "GLLD008",
    "varsyscode": "B"
  },
  {
    "value": 69,
    "datetime": 1536154560000,
    "code": "GLLD008",
    "varsyscode": "B"
  },
  {
    "value": 73,
    "datetime": 1536571560000,
    "code": "GLLD008",
    "varsyscode": "B"
  },
  {
    "value": 69,
    "datetime": 1536575160000,
    "code": "GLLD008",
    "varsyscode": "B"
  }
];

var helper = {};
// Group by day and code
var result = myArray.reduce(function(r, o) {
        var day = new Date(o.datetime).getFullYear() + '/' + new Date(o.datetime).getMonth() + '/' + new Date(o.datetime).getDay();
        var key = day + '-' + o.code;
        
        if (!helper[key]) {
            helper[key] = Object.assign({}, o);
            r.push(helper[key]);
        }
        return r;
    }, []);


result.forEach(function(element) {
    console.log(element.value + " - " + (new Date(element.datetime).toString()) + " - " + element.code + " - " + element.varsyscode);
});
```

Comment: Can you please share the actual array? This is not useful `Yes - Thu Sep 02 2018 10:03:10 GMT+0200 (CEST) - JVJF005 - Variable - Renal - Daily ` There is no `datetime` here

Comment: which value are you talking about?

Comment: I added columns names to my array, I hope you understand better. Value is the first column, datetime is the second column

Comment: Sorry I do this right now!

Comment: Please add a valid object literal / JSON. We can't copy this format to create a valid snippet in the answer. Also, how do you decide the *"maximum value for each code"* since the `code` is a string. Please create a [mcve] with a clear problem statement.

Comment: I tried to do a minimal example, please tell me if you need more infos

Comment: Yes I modified my post

Comment: Your input is clear now but can you please post the expected output and clarify how to get the output? There is no mention of `GLLD0015` in your input. This is still not a [mcve]

Comment: @adiga I'm not sure it matters that `GLLD0015` is not in the input data. Per the rules it's just a group key that could *turn up*.

Comment: @Louis *"at any point during the day"* means, even if any other entry in the array satisfies the rules?

Comment: @Yoshi I honestly don't know what OP wants. Input, output, and how to get the output. This is all I asked to clarify. Voting to close as no [mcve]. (And OP has added the expected output (in table form again) which has confused me further)

Comment: Rule for A > 6 & B > 60 is only applicable for GLLD008 (sorry adding that to post). I am sorry guys I am trying to be as clear as I can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few steps you need to implement in order to update the `code`.

1. Check if the `code` is `"GLLD008"`
2. Check if the `value` is numeric.
3. Evaluate the `varsyscode`

   1. Evaluate the `value`
   2. Update the `code`

You can add the following, before generating the `key`.

```
if (o.code === 'GLLD008' && isNumeric(o.value)) {
  switch (o.varsyscode) {
    case 'A':
      if (o.value > 6) {
        o.code = 'GLLD0015'
      }
      break;
    case 'B':
      if (o.value > 60) {
        o.code = 'GLLD0015'
      }
      break;
  }
}
```

## Implementation

```js
var myArray = [
  { "value": 5,      "datetime": 1536242590000, "code": "GLLD008", "varsyscode": "A" },
  { "value": 7,      "datetime": 1536579148000, "code": "GLLD008", "varsyscode": "A" },
  { "value": 6,      "datetime": 1536579688000, "code": "GLLD008", "varsyscode": "A" },
  { "value": 5,      "datetime": 1536833430000, "code": "GLLD008", "varsyscode": "A" },
  { "value": 85,     "datetime": 1536152820000, "code": "GLLD008", "varsyscode": "B" },
  { "value": 69,     "datetime": 1536154560000, "code": "GLLD008", "varsyscode": "B" },
  { "value": 73,     "datetime": 1536571560000, "code": "GLLD008", "varsyscode": "B" },
  { "value": 69,     "datetime": 1536575160000, "code": "GLLD008", "varsyscode": "B" },
  { "value": "APRV", "datetime": 1536152820000, "code": "GLLD008", "varsyscode": "C" },
  { "value": "APRV", "datetime": 1536575040000, "code": "GLLD008", "varsyscode": "C" },
  { "value": "APRV", "datetime": 1536590700000, "code": "GLLD008", "varsyscode": "C" }
];

var helper = {};
// Group by day and code
var result = myArray.reduce((r, o) => {
  var day = formatDate(o.datetime);
  if (o.code === 'GLLD008' && isNumeric(o.value)) {
    switch (o.varsyscode) {
      case 'A':
        if (o.value > 6) {
          o.code = 'GLLD0015'
        }
        break;
      case 'B':
        if (o.value > 60) {
          o.code = 'GLLD0015'
        }
        break;
    }
  }
  var key = day + '-' + o.code;
  if (!helper[key]) {
    helper[key] = Object.assign({}, o);
    r.push(helper[key]);
  }
  return r;
}, []);

var grouped = result.reduce((o, curr) => {
  let key = formatDate(curr.datetime);
  
  if (!isNumeric(curr.value)) {
    return o; // skip non-numeric value e.g. "APRV"
  }
  
  if (o[key] == null) {
    return Object.assign(o, { [key] : curr }); // store initial entry
  }
  
  let prev = o[key]; // get stored value for key

  // If you wanted the max value... (this is overriden below)
  if (curr.value > prev.value) {
    o[key] = curr;
  }

  // If you only want to keep "GLLD008"
  if (curr.code === 'GLLD008' && prev.code === 'GLLD0015') {
    o[key] = curr;
  }

  return o;
}, {});

result = Object.keys(grouped).map(key => grouped[key]); // map to list
result.sort((a, b) => new Date(a.datetime) - new Date(b.datetime)); // sort list

result.forEach(entry => {
  console.log([
    entry.value, formatDate(entry.datetime), entry.code, entry.varsyscode
  ].join(' - '));
});

function isNumeric(n) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}

function formatDate(date) {
  return ((d) => d.getFullYear() + '/' + d.getMonth() + '/' + d.getDate())(new Date(date));
}
//Edited
```

Comment: I forgot to say that GLLD015 & GLLD008 were exclusive in the last array. If there is both then GLLD008 only stays. If you could help me do that ? @Mr. Polywhirl

Comment: @Louis Which value do you go with then for 2018/8/10 A? Is the value 7 or 6?

Comment: AS GLLD008 stays i will go with 008 Value (6)

Comment: @Louis Just add/remove conditionals where needed to filter properly. I attempted to address the  case where both GLLD015 and GLLD008 exist for the same day.